# Convert void pointer to a dynamic type

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers

I am trying to convert a void pointer to a dynamic type.
For example, I passed double variable to `test1` function which I expected the sum function will work. But I got C2664 cannot convert argument error on `sum(*reinterpret_cast<myType*>(tmp))`.
If I using this, it will work.

```
double c= *reinterpret_cast<double*>(tmp); 
sum(c);
```

**How do I fix this?**

```
void sum(double a)
{
    cout << "sum:" << a+10 << endl;
}
  
void test1(void* tmp)
{
    typedef decltype(tmp) myType;
    sum(*reinterpret_cast<myType*>(tmp));
}

int main()
{
    double a = 87.7;
    test1(&a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Fyi, considering `tmp` is `void*`, were you expecting something *other* than `void*` from `decltype(tmp)` ? Please [**edit your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71948568/edit) to provide details of the problem you're having and the specific *question* you have

Comment: @WhozCraig  sry. I forget to add * on casting. It should be *reinterpret_cast<double*>(tmp);

Comment: Are you asking if there is some magic way you can recover `double*` from a pointer that *was* a `double*` but has been reduced to `void*` as a function parameter? Frankly, this wreaks of an XY problem. You're asking how to fix a problem with *your chosen solution*, but the actual problem you're trying to *solve* by your chosen solution remains elusive.

Comment: @WhozCraig: it's worse than that. `reinterpret_cast<double>(c);` simply won't compile.

Comment: Not the way you're trying it. The original type information is lost. Native types do not retain RTTI that can be dynamically cast to recovery. Only sufficiently equipped class types can do that. Is there a reason you're not using templates for this?

Comment: Don't use void pointers where they are not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, dynamic type is really only meaningful when you're using inheritance. For example, if you have code like this:

```cpp
class Base {};

class Derived : public Base {};

int main() {
    Base *b = new Derived;
}
```

In this case, `b` has a static type of `Base *`, but a dynamic type of `Derived *` (because it was declared as a pointer to a `Base`, but is actually pointing at an instance of `Derived`).

So, if you want to recover an actual dynamic type, you'll need to start by defining some base class, and some derived class(es), and convert between them. When/if you do that, you usually want to use `dynamic_cast` rather than `reinterpret_cast` to do the job (it'll automatically check the actual type, so the cast will fail if you try to cast to a type that it's not really pointing at). But in most cases, you want to define some sort of virtual function in the base class, and override it as needed in the derived classes, so you don't need to use `dynamic_cast` at all. Also note that `dynamic_cast` only works on classes that contain at least one virtual function (but if you're using public inheritance without any virtual functions, you're probably doing something wrong).

Alternatively, you can create basically a discriminated union. You'll need to store something to record what actual type is stored, and you'll use that to cast back to the correct when needed.

```cpp
enum type { FLOAT, DOUBLE };

struct value { 
    type t;
    void *value;
};

float f = 1.2f
double d = 3.2;

value v { FLOAT, &f };
value y { DOUBLE, &d };

void do_call(value v) {
    if (v.type == FLOAT) { 
        use_float(*reinterpret_cast<float *>(v.value));
    else if (v.type == DOUBLE)
        use_double(*reinterpret_cast<double *>(v.value));
}
```

The compiler, however, won't store anything in a `void *` to keep track of what type of object it's really pointing at. If you want to cast back from `void *` to `float` or `double` as applicable, you're going to have to store something to keep track of which type that actually was.

Rather than the latter, you might also want to look into using `std::variant`, which handles storing the type tag automatically, and can help automate most of the type dispatching as well (e.g., with `std::visit`). At least as typically used, this will act more like an actual tagged union though, so it stores the actual values, rather than pointers to values that are stored elsewhere.